# Why the image is not shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm trying to get image (jpg file) from `node.js` and display it in html tag (`img`), but the picture is not shown (as you can see:).

My node.js which handle the request looks:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

app.get('/pictureItem', function (req, res) {

    // imagesNames[0].name - contains the name of the image to send (jpg file)
    res.sendFile('/images/' + imagesNames[0].name, {root: __dirname })  
})
```

and my js code looks:

```
$.get("/pictureItem", function(data, status) 
                 {
                     console.log("got image");
                     $("#imageId").attr("src", data);                    
                 })
```

what am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `data` that is being returned?  It almost looks like you are returning the byte data of the file itself

Comment: What is the file that you're sending on request? Is it an `.html` file? Could you specify where your front-end `js` code is located

Comment: If, as Taplar surmises you are sending the byte data of the image, you're doing it wrong! All you need to display the image is to update the dom with the new image metadata, and the browser will fetch & render the image itself. 

Even if you did want the byte data, say to paint into a html5 canvas, it does not look like your client side 'get' request is actually asking for a file. There is no indication that it populates the 'imageNames' parameter.

And, in turn, it looks like the imageNames parameter is expected in the body, which is not standard procedure for a GET request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `'/pictureItem'` route in Express sends an image.

Your ajax call in your client code seems to be expecting to get an URL back, not an image:

```
$.get("/pictureItem", function(data, status) {
     console.log("got image");
     $("#imageId").attr("src", data);                    
});
```

The usual way you would do this is:

1. Set `$("#imageId").attr("src", data);` to an URL that your server knows how to serve the image for.
2. This will cause the browser to then request that URL from your server.
3. When your server gets that image request, it will send the image back.
4. The browser will display the image it got back from the server.

---

I'm not quite sure what the overall problem is you're trying to solve here (you don't show the overall logic of the operation), but you could just do this:

```
$("#imageId").attr("src", "/pictureItem");
```

And, then your existing server route would return the desired image when the browser requests the image from the `/pictureItem` route.

Comment: If I have multiple images, and I want to serve all of them with one request  (one get request from server), how can I set the "data" with one string and parse it in server in order to send the right image ?

Comment: @user3668129 - You don't typically serve multiple images with one request unless you're playing tricks with sprites (which are sub-images buried in one master image).  The browser requests an image, the server sends that on image.  If the browser wants more than one image, it requests them each separately.  Sorry, but I still don't understand what real overall problem you're trying to solve here.  Please edit your question to go back a few steps and describe what you're really trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Have you defined the middleware for static files? If yes you could define a `GET` method which retrieves the path to a specific image and return that so you can attach it to the `src` attribute.</strike>

Your `pictureItem` endpoint is return the image file itself. Whereas your src attribute expects a string so it can fetch the image itself.

server.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/Images'));
app.get('/pictureItem', function (req, res) {
    // returns a string as '/images/someimagename.jpg'.
    res.send('/images/'+imageNames[0].name);
});
```

someJavascript.js

```
$.get("/pictureItem", function(data, status) 
{
    console.log("Found image on url: " + data);
    $("#imageId").attr("src", data);                    
});
```